# smartif tag not working out correctly

Tags: django, templates

I'm using the smartif tag from [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/) (I'm holding on with regards to upgrading to 1.2) in my template for a certain boolean field like so:

```
{% if payment.extends_membership == "True" %}
   {% trans "Yes" %}
{% else %}
   {% trans "No" %}
{% endif %}
```

But whatever the value of `extends_membership` I get only `No` as the output.  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `extends_membership` is a string, rather than a boolean?

In this particular case, you don't need smartif anyway - if it is a bool, you can just do:

```
{% if payment.extends_membership %}
```

and if you're sure it's a string, this will work:

```
{% ifequal payment.extends_membership "True" %}
```

Comment: That did it Daniel...thnx :)...I got a bit confused there